# Find out what function is called on some event in JavaScript (in IE)

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

I have following scenario - I have some layout with a lot of JavaScript in it. Let's say it's provided by an external company and I have to understand it on my own. Is there any way to get name of the function which is called on some event? I mean I click button1, then button2 and I got something like this in the console:

> button1.onClick()
>
> button2.onCLick()
>
> someEventHandlerOnClick()

Is it possible to obtain this kind of behavior without manual coding console.log in each method? Is there any profiler or tool for it?

Especially I'd be delighted to see what jQuery event handler has been called after click (or other event).

Comment: If you are using firebug, you can see the event listeners for each DOM element.

Comment: @qtgye Thank you. I never used Firebug before, even if I heard about it. However it's not completely what I searched for. Moreover I'd like to find some tool for IE in particular.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$.each($._data($("#elementID")[0], "events"), function(i, event) {
  console.log(i);
  $.each(event, function(j, h) {
       console.log(h.handler);
  });
});
```

This will output all bounded event to an element with id `elementID`.
[Here is a useful fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9n6gh/)

Comment: Thank you, but it produces output only for single element, not each element on the page.

Comment: You need to do it for each element you want separately. There is no way to do that for all element together! That's very bad approach. In the debugging mode of your application, you should choose an element and inspect all bounded events to it with above method. Then you can choose other elements and repeat this method.

Comment: There isn't any automatic way for **each element on the page**! You need to do some works yourself!